# How to remove a custom word pattern from a text using NLTK with Python

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I am currently working on a project of analyzing the quality examination paper questions.In here I am using Python 3.4 with NLTK. 

So first I want to take out each question separately from the text.The question paper format is given below.

```
 (Q1). What is web 3.0?
 (Q2). Explain about blogs.
 (Q3). What is mean by semantic web?
       and so on ........
```

So now I want to extract the questions one by one without having the question number(Question number format is always same as given above).So my result should be something like this.

```
 What is web 3.0?
 Explain about blogs.
 What is mean by semantic web?
```

So  how can tackle this problem with python 3.4 with NLTK?
Thank you

Comment: Why do you need the NLTK for that? Looks like you could just remove it through a simple regular expression.

Comment: Yes Sir.I am using NLTK for my further analysis.I do not know whether NLTK is needed or not for this work.Any way,can you tell me how can i do it with regular expression?

Comment: Use re.sub: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to detect lines containing a question, then extract the question and drop the question number. The regexp for detecting a question label is

```
qnum_pattern = r"^\s*\(Q\d+\)\.\s+"
```

You can use it to pull out the questions like this:

```
questions = [ re.sub(qnum_pattern, "", line) for line in text if 
                                            re.search(qnum_pattern, line) ]
```

Obviously, `text` must be a list of lines or a file open for reading.

But if you had no idea how to approach this, you have your work cut out for you with the rest of the assignment. I recommend spending some time on the python tutorial or other introductory materials.

Answer (score 1):

In case every sentence starts with this pattern, what you ask for is easy to parse, you can use `split` to remove this prefix:

```
sentences = [ "(Q1). What is web 3.0?",
              "(Q2). Explain about blogs.",
              "(Q3). What is mean by semantic web?"]
for sen in sentences:
    print sen.split('). ',1)[1]
```

This will print:

```
What is web 3.0?
Explain about blogs.
What is mean by semantic web?
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `(QX)` always separated by a space before the text, you can do this:

```
>>> text = """(Q1). What is web 3.0?
...  (Q2). Explain about blogs.
...  (Q3). What is mean by semantic web?"""
>>> for line in text.split('\n'):
...     print line.strip().partition(' ')[2]
... 
What is web 3.0?
Explain about blogs.
What is mean by semantic web?
```